# Tricking Javascript variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a question that I could not find the answer, or perhaps cannot phrase the way it should...

I would like to trick javascript's way of handling variables...

Let's say in php I could do something like:

```
$test['usr_'.$id]=826
```

But when I try to do the same in Javascript/jQuery:

```
$("#usr_rank_h").val('rank_'+id);
```

It will output `rank_826` instead of the value of the `var rank_826`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent idiom in javascript is actually

```
var id = 826;

var test = {};
test['rank_'+id] = 826;
```

Which gives you back an object of the form

```
{
   'rank_826': 826
}
```

PS: I'm not sure why you are using jQuery in this case, are you getting the `id` from an `input` ?

Comment: I am passing data from php to an input... I am slowly getting into jQuery ... It might not be the best way for this instance but it works now and I was wanted to know anyway ! thanks !!